# Given a string, how can I add only unique characters from another string to it?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique, string-formatting, std

I've been trying many different things for hours now, I tried using **std::unique** but I was getting funky results, then I tried using **string::find**.
I feel like it would be easy to accomplish this if I used **std::vector**
I'm looking for an efficient way to do this using the standard library, I read though a lot of the questions on here and cpluplus.com on this subject but I couldn't use their answers to implement what I needed. I apologize if this is trivial but I'm tired of trying different things at this point.

**For example:**

```
int main(){

  std::string unique_chars;
  std::string new_string = "ABC"

  getUniqueChars(unique_chars, new_string);
  cout << unique_chars << endl;

  new_string = "ABDF"
  getUniqueChars(unique_chars, new_string);

  cout << unique_chars; 

  return 0;
}  

void getUniqueChars(string &unique_chars, string &new_string){

   //add only unique characters from new_string to unique_chars

   return;
}
```

Should output:

```
ABC
ABCDF
```

Comment: *"I feel like it would be easy to accomplish this if I used std::vector"* -- Have you attempted that? Did it work? Because if it did, it's extremely likely that the exact same solution would work for `std::string`.

Comment: When you say "funky results", what do you mean by that? And you didn't miss the part of [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) where it says "Removes all ***consecutive*** duplicate elements", which means that the string have to be [sorted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I tried it with vectors on a separate file and I got it to work with std::find but I couldnt get the same solution to work with std::string.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg let me try it again, paying close attention to that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg can I use `std::string::iterator` instead of `std::vectory<type>::iterator`?

Comment: If you want to iterate over a string, or pass an iterator to a string to a function, then yes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I just feel like it's inefficient to use the `std::unique` now that I think about it. Because I would have to add everything to the string then look for the unique values then trim the string. I was looking for a solution that could check the string and only add to it if a character doesnt already exists in it.

Comment: You need to sort your strings in one form or another. There isn't an efficient way to do what you want otherwise.

Comment: If you need super efficient code, you are probably better off not using `std::string` at all. What larger problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to do it. Add all characters from both strings into the set, and then create a new string from the set.

```
// Create a set of characters from `unique_str`
std::set<char> set(unique_chars.begin(), unique_chars.end());

// Insert the characters from `new_string`
set.insert(new_string.begin(), new_string.end());

// The set now contains only unique characters from both strings, no duplicates
// Convert back to a string
unique_chars = std::string(set.begin(), set.end());
```

If you have a C++11 capable compiler and standard library, and don't want the result sorted, then you could use [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) instead.

Comment: Does a set automatically get rid of duplicates?

Comment: I love the simplicity of this solution and it's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking to add to my "tool belt". 
Can you elaborate a little more on the complexity of this approach?

Also I'm fairly new to this site, should I edit the original question to include the new implementation with what you posted here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guidance. you have to do the job

1. Then concatenate both strings
2. Remove the duplicate

Here is how remove duplicates

`std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
str.erase(std::unique(str.begin(), str.end()), str.end());`

Comment: I was able to implement it successfully with this. However I am worried about the complexity in it. I'm trying to develop good practices when it comes to that and this piece of code will be performed many times(10!) times at least. So I'm wondering if there is a better approach to this.

Comment: Actually after reading `Joachim Pileborg` answer, I think you should fallow that way.

Comment: Ah, yes your method makes more sense now. Thank you for your approach I was able to solve it with it as well.

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it would be, I guess:

```
Algorithm:
```

Take the original string and hash it into a hashtable, based on each character.

Take each character from new string and check if hashtable bucket has already been marked.

If not marked, append it to original string else reject it.

```
Code(not tested):

string orig, new ;
char arr[26]={initialise with all alphabets}

for(int i=0;i<orig.size();i++)
arr[new[i]] = x;

for(int i=0;i<new.size();i++)
if(arr[new[i]] != x)
orig += new[i];
```

The complexity(for pre-processing) would be O(N) ie linear to original array length.